# must the silverlight plugin object tag be contained within a form

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Looking at the sample .html file generated on a silverlight 4 project we see that the object tag is inside a form.  (and the form has runat="server" for that matter)

Is there a reason that the plug-in must be within a form, and for that matter what does runat="server" mean in an html file (note I understand it's purpose in an aspx file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it doesn't need to be in a Form.  Even when using ASPX I tend to remove all the extra paraphenalia that comes with a default template for an ASPX page.

In html runat="server" means nothing unless someone has mapped html extension to the ASP.NET processor which would be quite a weird thing to do.